# Minimum datetime and maximum datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am receiving as a parameter a date, this date is in the format 04/24/2012, so in sql i need to be able to do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN (04/24/2012 at 12 am (StartDate)) 
    AND (04/24/2012 at 11:59 pm (EndDate))
```

I have two parameters StartDate and EndDate

```
@StartDate nvarchar(50),
@EndDate nvarchar(50),
```

Sometimes StartDate and EndDate are not the same date so it could be 4/24/2012 - 4/27/2012, this is working fine... the problem is when they are doing the same day.

Comment: What is the datatype of the OrderDate column?

Comment: Why are you using `nvarchar` parameters for something which is naturally a date, not a string?

Comment: **WHY** are `StartDate` and `EndDate` string types?? Doesn't make any sense at all - those should be `DATETIME` variables!

Comment: In addition to using properly typed parameters, please don't think about date/time ranges in terms of BETWEEN. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: @Jon Eskeet and at marc_s , its for a report and it does not allow me to pass from C# a datetime type, i have to pass them as strings.

Comment: If the parameters are strings and the OrderDate is datetime, you'll need to convert them (since between expects both operands to be of the same type as the test expression).  @Charleh's suggestion + conversion to datetime (so you can call dateadd), and using >= for the first test is going to be your best bet..

Comment: Okay thank you for the good pointers

Comment: @user710502: It sounds like you should tell us more about the constraints you're under. Using parameterized SQL with a `DateTime` parameter would clearly be the best solution, so please explain more about what *other* constraints you might be under. (Note that your chosen date format is unfortunate, given that it's not a sortable one...)

Comment: You are right Jon Skeet, although I have those parameters as nvarchar, there is a conversion to datetime within the same query. It is working fine now.. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using end date but doing

```
orderdate >= @startdate and orderdate < Dateadd(d, 1, @enddate)
```

This way includes all the time between startdate and enddate if they are on the same day. E.g. greater or equal to the start of the day but less than the start of the next day